# How can I test if '-' exists but NOT between character '[' and ']'?

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

How can I test if '-' exists but NOT between character '[' and ']' ?

For example:

**AFR-SADKJ** : Match

**safkdsjfs[9-0]** : Skipped (beacause  -exists but there is [ somewhere before and ] after

Can you advise?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Note that .NET has an infinite width lookbehind - quite handy here. Do you want to match a hyphen in `safkdsjfs[9-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-notmatch` operator in combination with a regular expression that matches a hyphen somewhere between square brackets:

```
PS C:\> $re = '\[.*-.*\]'
PS C:\> $s1 = 'AFR-SADKJ'
PS C:\> $s2 = 'safkdsjfs[9-0]'
PS C:\> $s3 = 'foobar'
PS C:\> $s1 -like '*-*' -and $s1 -notmatch $re
True
PS C:\> $s2 -like '*-*' -and $s2 -notmatch $re
False
PS C:\> $s3 -like '*-*' -and $s3 -notmatch $re
False
```

Note that you need two checks for this to work: one that confirms the presence of a hyphen and the second that checks if it's between square brackets. Otherwise you'd get false positives for strings that don't contain hyphens.

If you need this check frequently you may want to wrap it in a function:

```
function Test-Hyphen([string]$s) {
  $s -like '*-*' -and $s -notmatch '\[.*-.*\]'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(?![^[]*])
```

Here is the working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lZ3xT7/3)

Comment: Breaks on `AFR-SAD]KJ`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following RegEx:

```
(?!\[.*)-(?!.*\])
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/vZ3dB3/1)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
(?!\[.*)    # Do Not match if there is a [ then data
-           # Hyphen
(?!.*\])    # Do Not match if there is data then a ]
```

Comment: Breaks on `AFR-SAD]KJ`